# Illustrator CS6-How do I make swatches stay Global after Global Adjust?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, swatches

**[Adobe Illustrator CS6 / PC]**

I hope someone can help me. I'm usually able to find an answer through Google, but not this time.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is create a series of color schemes. While doing one of them, I looked to see if I could change only one attribute (Brightness, Saturation, etc.) across all swatches in a group.

The group at the very bottom **[image 1]** is a shade scheme of the same hue and saturation. Please note that all three are set to *Global* and are being used with objects. I was wanting to change the saturation of the entire group rather than meticulously do one at a time.

From searching, I found out about *Edit Colors* **[image 2]**
, then *Global Adjust*
**[image 3]**. Even though it does enable me to perform the changes I need, it removes *Global* from all of them **[image 4]**.

While trying to find a workaround, the closest I came was using *Randomly Changes Saturation and Brightness* **[image 5]**. However, it changes all except the first color in the group, but that one still stays *Global* **[image 6]**.

Is there a way I can change individual attributes for a group of swatches at once and have them all remain *Global*?  Many thanks and I appreciate the help!

**Updated Feb 9,2016:** Listed answer in question's body of text.
**Updated Jun 9,2016:** Moved answer text to answer section.

Comment: Does anybody know the answer to this?

Comment: I don't. But you should edit the answer part out of your question and add it as a separate answer. Would be a better reference for future users with the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Feb 9,2016:** Listed answer in question's body of text. 
**Updated Jun 9,2016:** Moved answer text to answer section.

In the five days since I asked this question, the "easiest" workaround I could figure out is thus.

[image: Reference]

I am also posting this as a reference for myself and others with a similar question, despite it not being the answer. In Edit Colors, under Global Adjust or whatever HSB, RGB, etc. option, after making the changes, don't save it to the current group. Rather, select the folder icon in the top right corner of the window **[image 1]** to save it as a new group.

As you can see in the swatches panel **[image 2]**, the original, more saturated, color group is still there with their Global setting intact. Beneath it, you'll also see a de-saturated non-Global duplicate group beneath it.

From here, the workaround is to grab each swatch and hover over the Global one you want it to overwrite. Release the swatch while holding ALT and it will instantly change the underlying swatches color to that of the one released, yet it will stay Global and recolor all associated objects.**[image 3]**

This may not be the most ideal of solutions, but it is still a lot quicker than typing or copy-pasting the numerical values to each swatch.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the swatches by **double-clicking** them in the swatch panel. If you edit a global swatch, and tick the `Preview` option, you'll see artwork update as you edit the swatch. Unfortunately, this means you have to edit *each* swatch individually.

`Recolor Artwork` has no ability to retain the global setting for swatches. (Not even in CC2015).